# How to describe this lady's hair

Tags: phrase-requests

How would you describe this lady's hair? 
[image]

I decided to use some metaphors like these:

***Her golden braids flow over her ears like two rivulets and conjoin in the back of her head to cascade down her shoulder.***

So, does the rivulet metaphor work here?

Comment: You may get a good answer at https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Actually this is essentially a rephrasing request and [strongly discouraged](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/are-requests-for-rephrasing-on-topic/537#537) on Writing, although you may be able to ask it in a way that's OK there. But as it stands this is off-topic here, I'm afraid: just saying "the style doesn't work me" doesn't help people with what **would** "work for you." Please read through the [tag help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) and see if you can improve the question so it's on-topic here.

Comment: @Andrew I think this (the following) is relevant here, inasmuch as we want to know what can validly be suggested as being more appropriate on Writing than here. Would a totally open 'Can you suggest a sentence which elegantly describes this lady's hair?' be acceptable there?

Comment: This is critiquing, involving addressing style as well as the elements of English, so off-topic. That said, your suggestion seems a little flowery and liberty-taking to accurately describe the hair in this photograph. _We can't see the full view_.  // 'Conjoin' is pretentious. / '[Meet] in the back of her head' would require urgent surgery.

Comment: What about the first part?                                                                                      Her golden braids flow over her ears like two rivulets and cascade down her shoulder.

Comment: Thanks for the arrow pointing to the hair, wouldn't have found it without that !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a phrasing request.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for writing advice.

Comment: If you're not asking opinion but the label for such work, it's a French braid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style is called a crown braid.  Crown braids are made up of one to many braids; here, the two braids form one crown braid, although you can also describe them as "crown braids."

The description of two braids flowing like rivulets  wouldn't evoke this particular image for me.  You might say "her crown braids trickled back like rivulets flowing above her ears, joining behind her head  to cascade down her back."

Now that's VERY high prose. If you don't want to be writing purple prose, or one of your highest scenes about a key characteristic of a lynchpin character in your story,  you should cut it way down to suit this particular character and scene.

Comment: That is just great: Her crown braids trickled back like rivulets flowing above her ears, joining behind her head to cascade down her back.

Comment: Hello, P. The type of question here belongs on Writing.SE, if anywhere. ELU deals with English Language in the sense of 'rather than English Lit' questions. Grammar, single word choice, meaning of idioms, punctuation etc. Nuts and bolts rather than lit crit.